# Palindrome insertion challenge

Tags: python, programming-challenge, strings

Here is my solution to the following **Daily Coding Problem challenge**

> Given a string, find the palindrome that can be made by inserting the
>   fewest number of characters as possible anywhere in the word. If there
>   is more than one palindrome of minimum length that can be made, return
>   the lexicographically earliest one (the first one alphabetically).

**Example**

`Input`: race

`Output`: ecarace

I used a PEP8 checker for this code and the only issue I couldn't fix was the "UPPER_CASE" naming style as I don't understand what I am supposed to do to fix this

```
import itertools

def find_palindrome(word, new_strings) -> str:
    """Find the first palindromic word of a given string by adding new letters"""
    for add_string in new_strings:
        for index in range(len(word)):
            new_word = word[:index] + "".join(add_string) + word[index:]
            if new_word == new_word[::-1]:
                return new_word

if __name__ == "__main__":
    word = "r"
    if word != word[::-1]:
        new_strings = sorted(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.permutations(word, n)
                                                            for n in range(len(word)+1))))
        print(find_palindrome(word, new_strings))
    else:
        print(word)
```

**EDIT**
I noticed the `find_palindrome` function didn't return the first alphabetic palindrome so here is an update for this function

```
def find_palindrome(word, new_strings) -> str:
    """Find the first palindromic word of a given string by adding new letters"""
    add_string_length = 0
    list_new_words = []
    for add_string in new_strings:
        if len(add_string) > add_string_length and list_new_words:
            return (sorted(list_new_words)[0])
        add_string_length = len(add_string)
        for index in range(len(word)+1):
            new_word = word[:index] + "".join(add_string) + word[index:]
            if new_word == new_word[::-1]:
                list_new_words.append(new_word)
```

**EDIT 2**: 
It turns out I had updated the main function too, so here is the update for that:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    word = "race"
    if word != word[::-1]:
        new_strings = sorted(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.permutations(word, n)
                                                            for n in range(len(word)+1))),key=len)

        print(find_palindrome(word, new_strings))
    else:
        print(word)
```

Comment: Ignore the "UPPER_CASE" warnings, it's because you have code in global scope. If you put it in a function it doesn't complain.

Comment: @EML - I believe your update doesn't work for the word "`race`". It prints out "`racecar`" instead of "`ecarace`".

Comment: Sorry...I had updated the main function too to set the ```sorted key = len```. Posted update above