# Zig-zag function - coded solution

Tags: python, programming-challenge, strings

Here is my coded solution to the [LeetCode zig-zag](https://leetcode.com/problems/zigzag-conversion/) problem -

> *The string "`PAYPALISHIRING`" is written in a zigzag pattern on a given
>   number of rows like this (you may want to display this pattern in a
>   fixed font for better legibility) -*
>
> ```
> P   A   H   N 
> A P L S I I G 
> Y   I   R
> ```
>
> *And then read line by line: "`PAHNAPLSIIGYIR`"*
>
> *Write the code that will take a string and make this conversion given
>   a number of rows.*

I know the final line is a bit messy, and I could unpack it into a two-line `for` loop, but I really like single-line `for` loops.

```
def zigzag() -> list:
    """Returns the zig-zag word of a given input as a list."""
    array = []
    for _ in range(num_rows):
        array.append([])
    increasing = 1
    array_index = 0
    word_index = 0
    while word_index < len(word):
        if increasing:
            array[array_index].append(word[word_index])
            array_index += 1
            word_index += 1
        else:
            array[array_index].append(word[word_index])
            array_index -= 1
            word_index += 1
        if array_index == -1 and increasing == 0:
            increasing = 1
            array_index = 1
        if array_index == num_rows and increasing == 1:
            increasing = 0
            array_index = num_rows - 2
    return array

if __name__ == "__main__":
    word = "PAYPALISHIRING"
    num_rows = 3
    print("".join(line for array in zigzag() for line in array))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) implementation is great, now to focus on being concise -

While you have started writing immaculate programs, as in [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/221930/palindrome-insertion-challenge) and your current question, I believe you should start making your programs more concise. This decreases memory space and sometimes, makes your program faster. Also, I'm glad to see you've started implementing the [`if __name__ == '__main__'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do/419185#419185) guard.

Here's one approach you could use to make your program really concise and fast -

```
def zigzag(word: str, num_rows: int) -> str:

    ans = [''] * num_rows
    x = 0
    direction = 1
    for i in word:
        ans[x] += i
        if 0 <= x + direction < num_rows:
             x += direction
        else:
             direction *= -1
             x += direction
    return ''.join(ans)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(zigzag("PAYPALISHIRING", 3))
```

Here, I believe that it would be better if you don't declare `word` and `num_rows` before calling the function. This -

```
print(zigzag("PAYPALISHIRING", 3))
```

looks much shorter (and better) than -

> ```
> word = "PAYPALISHIRING"
> num_rows = 3
> print("".join(line for array in zigzag() for line in array))
> ```

Also, (hey, I'm *kind of* like a beginner, so please correct me if I'm wrong) I feel that you should perform the `.join()` function, or any other function really, in the principal function, as I have done above -

```
# rest of the principal function
return ''.join(ans)
```

Just use the `if __name__ == __main__` guard to (simply) call the principal function and execute the entire program (you *shouldn't* really perform any other function(s) in it *except* calling the principal function to execute it) -

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(zigzag("PAYPALISHIRING", 3))
```

---

Also, I would rename `increasing` to `direction` as it suits this task better ("the value of "`direction`" changes only when we have moved up to the topmost row or moved down to the bottommost row" (taken from [Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/zigzag-conversion/solution/)). If you're wondering what `*=` means, it's just another way of doing `x = x * 5`, which is specified [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/operators#assignment).

Also, you could make -

> ```
> array = []
> for _ in range(num_rows):
>     array.append([])
> ```

```
num_rows = 3
print(array)
# [[], [], []]
```

more concise by just simply initializing it -

```
array = [[] for _ in range(num_rows)]  # Thanks to Maarten Fabré

num_rows = 3
print(array)
# [[], [], []]
```

See how concise you can get by doing this? This removes the need to use `.append()`, which, in this case, is unnecessary (this will also take up less memory space).

---

> *I know the final line is a bit messy, and I could unpack it into a
>   two-line for loop but I really like single-line for loops.*

Nah, don't worry. As far as I know,

```
print("".join(line for array in zigzag() for line in array))
```

is so much more concise than unpacking it into a two-line `for` loop. I'm glad you like single-line `for` loops :)

Here are the times taken for each function -

Your function -

```
%timeit "".join(line for array in zigzag() for line in array)
8.34 µs ± 834 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

---

My function -

```
%timeit zigzag("PAYPALISHIRING", 3)
4.19 µs ± 134 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

As you can see above, the time taken for execution has been approximately halved, which also shows that making your function concise, down to what I have done in my function, can make your program much faster.

Here is the Leetcode result for my program (if need be) -

> [image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm glad you like the improvements in PEP8. I've started using a PEP8 checker on my code as I am aware this is often the main feedback. I appreciate your help in pushing me towards this :)

Comment: As a point I tried ```array = [[]] * num_rows``` but appending an item to array[0] appends it too array[1] and array[2] as well. Don't know why though

Comment: @EML - Sorry for the late reply (Internet was down). I believe I have made a mistake and have removed the content from my answer. Sorry for any inconveniences ;(

Comment: Thanks. Don't worry. I appreciate all your help. Its nice to know that I can teach you things too about Python (even if I come across these things by accident myself) :)

Comment: Instead of `array = [[]] * 3` you need `[[] for _ in range (num_rows)]`. Else you just chop copy the same reference you a list 3 times

Comment: Thanks @MaartenFabré. I have edited my answer according to your suggestion.

Comment: @EML - I have edited my answer according to Martin Fabré's suggestion. Please take a look at it.

Comment: Thanks. That is an elegant way around the problem

Comment: You can also take the `x += direction` out of the if else, since it's the same for both. Just negate the condition